# An application of Tarski-Seidenberg Theorem

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, semialgebraic-geometry

I am reading the paper "A. D. Ioffe, An invitation to tame optimization, SIAM J. Optim., 19 (2009), 1894–1917" and stuck at Proposition 3.1. The author claims  (in the language of semi-algebraic geometry) that if $\varphi:\mathbb{R}^n\times\mathbb{R}^m\rightarrow\overline{\mathbb{R}}$ is a semi-algebraic function then the function
$$\psi(x):=\sup_{\varepsilon>0}\inf_{0<\left\|h\right\|<\varepsilon}\varphi(x,h)$$
is also semi-algebraic. I tried to use the Tarski-Seidenberg Theorem to prove this claim but I could not. Although it is easy to show that $g(x)=\inf_{h\in S}\varphi(x,h)$ is semi-algebraic for any semi-algebraic set $S\subset \mathbb{R}^m$, it seems too hard for me to deal with $\inf_{0<\left\|h\right\|<\varepsilon}\varphi(x,h)$ where the infimum is taken respect to $\varepsilon$ which is not fixed.

I am very grateful to you if you could help me to overcome this obstacle. Thank you for your help!

Comment: This task becomes much easier if one uses Tarski-Seidenberg in the "logical" form, which provides elimination of quantifiers.  Your $\psi$ is easily definable from $\varphi$ using several  quantifiers, and eliminating those quantifiers gives you a semi-algebraic expression for $\psi$. (A "geometric" form of T-S, dealing with projections of semi-algebraic sets, lets you deal with the quantifiers one at a time. It's ultimately equivalent to the logic form but more work to apply.)

Comment: @AndreasBlass Thank you for your advice. Could you please tell me some references where I can find this geometric form and its applications? Sorry if my question is silly since this area is very new to me.

Comment: As a logician, I'm accustomed to using exclusively the logical form.that should be findable by googling "quantifier elimination for real-closed fields". (I had assumed you already knew the geometric version, since that could lead to the difficulty you mentioned in hte question.)